# Communicate Between Components in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Here is my react-native code:

```
<NavigatorIOS
ref='nav'
style={styles.container}
initialRoute={{
    title: 'List',
    component: TaskList,
    rightButtonTitle: 'new',
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
        this.refs.nav.push({ 
        title: 'Add Task',
        component: AddTask
        });
    }
}} />
```

How can I push some notifications from the AddTask component to the TaskList component?

The docs said that "*For communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event system.*"

So I need set up a global event system?

Comment: Do you have a renderScene method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [communicate-between-components](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) said:

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) pattern is one of the possible
>   ways to arrange this.

You can use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) in the react-native project.

Here is a demo for Flux + React-Native:
[image]

You can check out the source code from [github](https://github.com/backslash112/react-native_flux_demo).

Answer (score 0):

I work with Navigator but I think it's the same thing with NavigatorIOS.

You can pass props like your title, component :

```
<NavigatorIOS
ref='nav'
style={styles.container}
initialRoute={{
  title: 'List',
  component: TaskList,
  rightButtonTitle: 'new',
  onRightButtonPress: () => {
    this.refs.nav.push({ 
    title: 'Add Task',
    component: AddTask
    myInformation:'information'
    });
  }
}} />
```

'information' can be replace by global variable.

To pass props from AddTask to TackList, it's the same thing. You can pass props in pop or replace or push